# generate PDF from member information

Tags: database, user-meta, membership, pdf

I'm building a website with membership and I would like to generate a pdf using user information such as name and email and to make it downloadable in his member space.

I've seen that there are some plugins to do that from a form but I don't want the user to fill-up a form because they could then write any name for anyone as the membership isn't free and the pdf is a proof of subscription.

I am not looking for a complicated pdf, just a page with the full name of the user, a prewritten sentence and a signature.
Maybe there is a solution in HTML or PHP and/or using get_user_data but I don't know them.

Thank you in advance and please don't hesitate If you have any questions for me,

Charles Raffegeau

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Take a look at http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Yes, use FPDF in a plugin that pulls in their details and either saves the file on the server or just outputs it directly to the user on a certain admin page.